# frequency of string (comma separated) in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, frequency, word-cloud

I'm trying to find the frequency of strings from the field "Select Investors" on this website https://www.cbinsights.com/research-unicorn-companies

Is there a way to pull out the frequency of each of the comma separated strings?

For example, how frequent does the term "Sequoia Capital China" show up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution provided by @Mazhar checks whether a certain term is a substring of a string delimited by commas. As a consequence, the number of occurrences of `'Sequoia Capital'` returned by this approach is the sum of the occurrences of all the strings that contain `'Sequoia Capital'`, namely `'Sequoia Capital'`, `'Sequoia Capital China'`, `'Sequoia Capital India'`, `'Sequoia Capital Israel'` and `'and Sequoia Capital China'`. The following code avoids that issue:

```py
import pandas as pd
from collections import defaultdict

url = "https://www.cbinsights.com/research-unicorn-companies"
df = pd.read_html(url)[0]

freqs = defaultdict(int)
for group in df['Select Investors']:
    if hasattr(group, 'lower'):
        for raw_investor in group.lower().split(','):
            investor = raw_investor.strip()
            # Ignore empty strings produced by wrong data like this:
            # 'B Capital Group,, GE Ventures, McKesson Ventures'
            if investor:
                freqs[investor] += 1
```

##### Demo

```
In [57]: freqs['sequoia capital']
Out[57]: 41

In [58]: freqs['sequoia capital china']
Out[58]: 46

In [59]: freqs['sequoia capital india']
Out[59]: 25

In [60]: freqs['sequoia capital israel']
Out[60]: 2

In [61]: freqs['and sequoia capital china']
Out[61]: 1
```

The sum of occurrences is 115, which coincides with the frequency returned for `'sequoia capital'` by the currently accepted solution.

Answer (score 1):

I made this correct, more pythonic way

```
import itertools
import collections
import pandas as pd


def fun(x):
    x = map(lambda y: y.strip().lower(), str(x).split(','))
    return filter(lambda y: y and y != 'nan', x)


# Extract data
url = "https://www.cbinsights.com/research-unicorn-companies"
df = pd.read_html(url)
first_df = df[0]


# Process
investor = first_df['Select Investors'].apply(lambda x: fun(x))
investor = investor.values.flatten()
investor = list(itertools.chain(*investor))

# Organize
final_data = collections.Counter(investor).items()
final_df = pd.DataFrame(final_data, columns=['Investor', 'Frequency'])
final_df
```

Output:

```
    Investor                                        Frequency
0   Sequoia Capital China                           46
1   SIG Asia Investments                            3
2   Sina Weibo                                      2
3   Softbank Group                                  9
4   Founders Fund                                   16
...     ...     ...
1187    Motive Partners. Apollo Global Management   1
1188    JBV Capital                                 1
1189    Array Ventures                              1
1190    AWZ Ventures                                1
1191    Endiya Partners                             1
```

Comment: How do i convert this output into a dataframe?

Comment: data=[]    
in a loop     
data.append([string, frequency])    
outside the loop    
pd.DataFrame(data,columns=["investor","frequency"])

Comment: Now, I make it right. Thanks for noticing & mention this @jezrael

Comment: Your solution is still wrong as it converts `'Grandland'` and `'Creandum'` into `'Grl'` and `'Creum'`, respectively

Comment: I Just apply an extra pre process, which I removed now :)

Comment: Not yet correct. `'nan' in final_df['Investor'].values` is evaluated as `True`, but no investor is called `'nan'`.

Comment: I have checked & my ```answer is right```. Even in your answer I can see frequency is available for ```frequency[''] = 2``` according to your comment it looks like your answer is also wrong. But it's not the case. The main concern is whether we can find accurate frequency for our given name or not. Which is clearly working in my ans & yours too.

Comment: I have edited my answer to fix the issue you mentioned. I also checked yours, and `'nan' in investor` still returns `True` (although there is no investor with that name). This is due to the fact that you cast all the values of `first_df['Select Investors']` to `str`. The problem is that the dataset contains a few `NaN`'s and the helper function `fun()` converts those null values into `'nan'`.

Comment: I already told you, it's not a matter at all to handle those issues. But other investor numbers are right except some garbage investors like ```("", "nan",...). But as you mentioned now I handle those things also .

Comment: I beg to differ. In my opinion, for a solution to be deemed correct, it has to deal adequately with missing/faulty data.